# Top bar broken on SE

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com, network-profile

If I go to my [SE profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2930247/felipep) the top bar looks broken

[image]

I'm using last version of chrome.

EDIT: Today (Nov 19) something out there got updated and the problem is gone.

Comment: Did you try using ctrl+f5 to ensure your css isn't cached? And also, are you running any extensions?

Comment: yes, also clean cache + hard reload

Comment: Anything not loading in the developer tools? This looks like a css file isn't loading.

Comment: Similarly, I'm [not able to see the site selector](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zQVKI.png) on MSO and Stack Overflow. Using Chrome as well, works on IE.

Comment: console is empty

Comment: What version of Chrome, Felipe and @gunr2171?

Comment: @Oded, 38.0.2125.111 m, but it says it is updating right now.

Comment: Version 38.0.2125.122 m, to me looks like 'hidden-text' class is not working here

Comment: Just updated to the version FelipeP has. Now it's working on SO, but [still broken on MSO](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LXQYS.png).

Comment: Yeah, that got broken for a short while yesterday and a fix was pushed. Looks like you have a bad proxy caching the old CSS somewhere between you and us :(

Comment: Strangely this started less than a half hour ago, but I can understand bad middle-men.

Comment: don't worry, I'm living in the past :)

Comment: One thing to try with Chrome - close all browser instances after clearing the cache.

Comment: @Oded, didn't that already happened after the chrome update?

Comment: @FelipeP - suppose it did. Just thinking about things to try.

Comment: Just in case it helps, I'm not using any extensions

Comment: @FelipeP, it seems we have two different problems going on. Me and Steven have problems with AdBlock, and you have something else.

Comment: @gunr2171 maybe the best would be to ask another question since the cause looks very different (I won't, but if you are using that extension you could I guess)

Comment: +200? Where did you get +200?

Comment: @nicael I just created my account here to post this issue, I had an SO account, so "You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network"

Comment: :) Ok, understood

Comment: fixed this using jQuery `$('.hidden-text').hide()`, [this was true](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my particular issue, I found that what is happening (still now) is what @Oded pointed out in a comment:

> Looks like you have a bad proxy caching the old CSS somewhere between
>   you and us :(

I checked this by visiting my SE profile using a proxy, that way the UI is fine and the `hiddent-text` class is loaded correctly.

EDIT: Today (Nov 19) something out there got updated and the problem is gone.

For the other [issue described in the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQVKI.png), please look at @Steven Penny's answer.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the issue was [Fanboy’s Social Blocking List](http://easylist.adblockplus.org) for Adblock Plus.

Disabling it has brought back the missing elements, however this is not ideal
because I use that filter for a reason. I have [filed a report](http://reports.adblockplus.org/157c40b2-7ed4-4016-8a2b-0ce0d04d74b7) with Adblock
Plus.

Update

The report still says `Status: unknown` but the issue appears to be resolved.

Comment: Oh god you're right. How dare they betray my trust.

Comment: Confirming - that list does kill the topbar.