# Invisible top bar

Tags: bug, status-norepro, top-bar

My top bar is invisible for SE sites (I've only checked Chemistry, SO and P.SE) while using Chrome (38.0.2125.111 m) but not with FireFox or IE (ew)

Interestingly, the top bar does show up here on M.SE.

I did see the question [Top bar broken on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243526/top-bar-broken-on-se) but I'm seeing a different issue than that, or at least it is manifesting in a different way.

[image]

Comment: Got adblock plus? Try disabling it.

Comment: Yes, but it is disabled for all SE sites (and I just manually redisabled it and nothing changed)

Comment: Some other ad blocker? Extension? Try disabling them all and see what happens.

Comment: That's my only ad blocker.  I've disabled my other extensions and nothing changed as well.

Comment: When you open the dev tools and refresh, is there any 400 or 500 responses?

Comment: No. However I forgot to disable tampermonkey before, and doing it now has fixed the issue so it was probably something in there.